# Scan windows drive for errors externally

Tags: windows

So I'm looking for a software that will check a windows drive for errors, but the only ones I can find will scan the boot drive on my computer (I have another drive with win 10 on it that won't load past the welcome screen). Any software that will check/repair it?

Answer (score 1):

From an administrative command prompt
chkdsk /r c:  (replace drive letter) 
will fix file system errors.

**sfc** can be made to run on a second drive

```
/OFFWINDIR=<offline windows directory> /OFFBOOTDIR=<offline boot directory>
```

1. Unplug hard drive from pc2
2. Attach as a second hard drive to PC 1.

OR

1. Place hard drive from PC2 into USB enclosure
2. Connect USB enclosure to PC 1.

OR

1. Download Windows 10 ISO --windows media creation tool
2. Get a blank USB stick
3. Make a bootable windows 10 USB
4. Boot PC2 with said stick
5. At first screen SHIFT AND F10 gets you a command prompt
6. chkdsk /f or chkdsk /r

Your options depend on how badly windows is damaged if it just bad sector(s) you can just chkdsk /r all the drives.

Some tools are harder to run or don't run when booting from the windows install media.  **sfc** requires several command line switches.

OR

1. Download a linux live ISO
2. Make bootable USB (unetbootin) or make burn a DVD

Gparted can also check disk for errors.  Many LIVE distro have this tool included.

OR

Buy spinrite from grc.com it creates a bootable option.  I think an ISO you can make a bootable USB stick.  Only solves hard drive issues.

OR

Use one of a thousand other bootable tools.